# CDR report not showing (Astrisk 1.8 + FreePBX 12)

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I'm running Asterisk 1.8 with FreePBX 12, but CDR report doesn't show any result in the database.

I've tried many methods to resolve the problem, but can't seem to figure it out
.
Is there someone who can help me??

The output from my console is;

```
cl-t222-132cl*CLI> cdr show status
Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
Logging: Enabled
Mode: Simple
Log unanswered calls: No

* Registered Backends
-------------------
cdr-custom csv
```

I have just found out that `cdr_mysql` has been deprecated in Asterisk 1.8. To get it working with MySQL I will need to use ODBC and cdr_adaptive_odbc module. If anyone can help me out that would be great.

Sincerely;

Comment: Which cdr are you using? and what if anything is output on the console?

Comment: Tx for your reply, as i said i'm using Asterisk 1.8, what i noticed, the record  are not saved in cdr table (database)

Comment: Sorry I ment which cdr back-end, but you said database. mysql? Is this a fresh install? and did you configure install odbc? I have asterisk 13 with a running cdr in mysql. I can find you my config if you think that may help. I've not dont anything via FreePBX before though...

Comment: tx again, for CDR Report version is : 12.0.23
i've installed it last september, asterisk is working fine, it was completly new installation (for cdr table i restored my old table from old system), but since last september no recored was saved in this table

Comment: from the asterisks console (`asterisks -r`) can you type `cdr show status` and post the output in your question please.

Comment: cl-t222-132cl*CLI> cdr show status

Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
  Logging:                    Enabled
  Mode:                       Simple
  Log unanswered calls:       No

* Registered Backends
  -------------------
    cdr-custom
    csv

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution, but found something interesting.
cdr_mysql has been deprecated in Asterisk 1.8. To get it working with MySQL i will need to use ODBC and cdr_adaptive_odbc module.

Answer (score 0):

As you have just found out `cdr_mysql` has been deprecated in Asterisk 1.8. To get it working with MySQL you will need to use ODBC and `cdr_adaptive_odbc` module.

Have a look at these two sites - they should be able to provide you with the basic info to get something up & running.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+odbc

https://www.ringroost.com/blog/asterisk-odbc-cdr-mysql-on-ubuntu/

If you have an old cdr db that you want to keep make sure you update the tables to the newer format and you should be good to go. If you need any more help or further advise please *edit your question* with the link below it.

Having seen your comments below it sounds like you may not have loaded the correct module(s) from `make menuselect`

Re-run the command then go to `Resource Modules` and select `res_odbc` Then go up to `Call Detail Recording` and select `cdr_odbc`

Comment: I follwed typically this link : http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/installing_configuring_odbc.html , and recompiled my asterisk, but when i try to execute odbc show , i get this message : No such command 'odbc show' (type 'core show help odbc show' for other possible commands)

Comment: Did you build/install asterisk with odbc support? in a console do `module show like odbc` It sounds like the module is not loaded.

Comment: This is what i did : yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel libtool-ltdl libtool-ltdl-devel then recompiled my asterisk by : ./configure
$ make menuselect
$ make install , but i noticed that res_odbc.so is not in modules folder, so it can't be loaded, i don't know what i missed

Comment: I'm trying to check res_odbc, but i find XXX infront of it, so i can't check it

Comment: Ok when i go to Resource Modules > res_odbc, i find XXX so i can't select it, and in Call Detail Recording , i find only XXX cdr_adaptive_odbc

Comment: when you select either of those have a look at the bottom of the page it should say what it depends on. It's bottom left from memory. let me know

Comment: I found these dependices :
XXX res_config_odbc  (Depends on: res_odbc(M)), 
XXX res_odbc (Depends on: generic_odbc(E), ltdl(E)), 


XXX cdr_adaptive_odbc (Depends on: res_odbc(M))

Comment: it sounds like your still missing a component from when you installed odbc. what os & what db are you using?

Comment: I'm using Centos6 + Mysql 5

Comment: Maybe - depends if this is production box or not. It would be nice to try and find out what dep your missing. But if you are going to do an upgrade I'd say do a clean install of the current version + drivers + (making sure you remove all the old configs and libs)

Comment: Do you have a tutorial? cuz this is my first time to do that, i've installed asterisk and configure it, but i don't have any idea how to update it. by the way, i'm facing an other issue, when i try to compile asterisk, i made : make distclean then  ./configure, but when i launch : make menuselect i get this error : make: *** [makeopts] Error 1

Comment: sounds like you have broken something. You could delete that source and re-download the exact older version and try again. otherwise have a look at https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Installing+Asterisk+From+Source it should give you all the info you need to build from source

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to download the new source, il will break really other files, what is your opinion?

Comment: You could re-download the old (your specific version) of the source to a *new* folder. Provided you don't do a `make install` it won't overwrite anything else but it will allow you to re-build what you have. Older downloads can be found at http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/ I think you might be best to find a test machine where you can build a new version and have a play so you get some more experience

Comment: I resolved the probem ( make problem), while launching ./configure, there were a warning (libxml2 was not available, so i installed and make menuselect worked), now m still looking for a solution for odbc

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve finally my problem and loaded res_odbc, i had to restart asterisk to save all modification, now when i launch CLR, i get these errors :

[Jun 18 19:35:39] WARNING[25387]: res_odbc.c:646 ast_odbc_prepare_and_execute: SQL Execute error -1! Verifying connection to asterisk [asterisk-connector]...

[Jun 18 19:35:39] WARNING[25387]: res_odbc.c:744 ast_odbc_sanity_check: Connection is down attempting to reconnect...

[Jun 18 19:35:39] NOTICE[25387]: res_odbc.c:1480 odbc_obj_connect: Connecting asterisk

[Jun 18 19:35:39] NOTICE[25387]: res_odbc.c:1510 odbc_obj_connect: res_odbc: Connected to asterisk [asterisk-connector]

[Jun 18 19:35:39] WARNING[25387]: app_voicemail.c:5145 inboxcount2: SQL Execute error! [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voicemessages WHERE dir = '/var/spool/asterisk/voicemail/default/799/INBOX']

If someone has an idea, can help me.

Thanks;